# Why can't Visual C++ partially specialize a class inside a template?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, inner-classes, partial-specialization

When I try to run this code in Visual C++ (2015)

```
template<int V>
struct outer
{
    template<int U, bool>
    struct inner;
};
template<int V>
template<bool B>
struct outer<V>::inner<V, B> { enum { value = 0 }; };

int main()
{
    return outer<1>::inner<1, false>::value;
}
```

I get the error

```
Temp.cpp(13): error C2027: use of undefined type 'outer<1>::inner<1,false>'
Temp.cpp(13): note: see declaration of 'outer<1>::inner<1,false>'
Temp.cpp(13): error C2065: 'value': undeclared identifier
```

However, [it compiles and runs fine on GCC](https://ideone.com/5Va0BN) and Clang.

Three questions:

1. If the partial specialization isn't partially specializing, what *is* it doing?
2. Why does this happen? Is it a bug, or is there really a problem with this code?
3. Is there a workaround that lets you still use the inner template class inside the inner template class, or is the only solution to move the template arguments outside?

Comment: Upgrade to VS 2017?  It compiles without complaint there.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: Ack, so it's a bug? Unfortunately upgrading is easier said than done...

Comment: Can't reproduce with VS2017.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation in the implementation of C++ in Visual C++ 2015 (one of many).

This does work in Visual C++ 2017, so a version upgrade may be necessary.

Comment: Any chance you could address the other questions in the post?